# Flutter run gets stuck on "Running Xcode build"

Tags: ios, flutter

App runs on macOS but when I try `fluter run -v` on iOS(iPad), it gets stuck on the following:

> Running Xcode build...
> [   +2 ms] executing: [/Users/apfox500/Documents/GitHub/AAC-App/ios/] xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner BUILD_DIR=/Users/apfox500/Documents/GitHub/AAC-App/build/ios -sdk
> iphoneos -destination id=00008101-001868481EE9001E ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES ARCHS=arm64 SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/hg/mls6tcw111sgfh2t7v539zrh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.j2rCNj/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirBj4KR5/pipe_to_stdout -resultBundlePath
> /var/folders/hg/mls6tcw111sgfh2t7v539zrh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.j2rCNj/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirBj4KR5/temporary_xcresult_bundle -resultBundleVersion 3 FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO

I've run flutter doctor and nothing is wrong, tried `flutter clean` and `pod deintegrate`/`pod install` many times as well as building directly from Xcode, with nothing working.

Comment: It doesn't seem to throw an error. How long is it stuck for?

Comment: 2 hours is when I usually gave up

Comment: Your machine probably has less space to process

Comment: Any ideas then?

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` run this in terminal, and also restart your machine once

Comment: didn't work, still stuck on same line